# Is there compatibility between Uni<> and Reactor's Mono<>?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, hibernate-reactive

I'm trying to connect Hibernate Reactive and Spring WebFlux(Project Reactor most).
The problem is that `Uni<>`(Hibernate Reactive type) replaces `Mono<>` (Reactive type from Project Reactor), and from now, behaviour is not such obviously, as Project Reactor provides without other reactive types.

Is there are some tools for compatibility between Uni<> and Reactor's Mono<>/Flux<>?

Already Investigated GitHub repos, tried to connect reactive types via custom spring starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is support to convert between the two type systems.

Add the following dependency...

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
    <artifactId>mutiny-reactor</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

...and use the following code:

```java
Mono<T> monoFromUni = uni.convert().with(UniReactorConverters.toMono());
```

You can find detailed documentation here: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/1.7.0/guides/converters/